# How to directly read posterior probs in HTK?

Tags: probability, htk

Greeting fellows,

I am desperately trying to find what files I will have to modify in htk 3.4, so that I can directly read sequences of posterior probs for phonemes/monophones for utterances and directly forward them to the decoder, given both the acoustic and language model.

More detailed, I am following the HTK tutorial to and including step 9, I just want to work on monophones. My (own, specific) feature vectors are sequences of vectors with probabilities for 3 states of each phoneme, that is something like

(p(aa_begin), p(aa_mid), p(aa_end), ..., p(z_begin), p(z_mid), p(z_end))

for each frame in the utterance, where the entries are, as mentioned above, already posterior probs.

Any idea which files I need to modify to read those from my (specific) files (own binary format) and how to directly forward them to the decoder? Best so that I can use HVite & HEResult to get the results?

Thanks a lot for help,
G.

Comment: Modifying HTK to use your posteriors instead of the GMM likelihoods will be complicated. You might be able to do it either in the ProcessFile function in HVite.c or the ProcessObservation function in HRec.c. It sounds like what you want is very similar to Hybrid-HMM systems; googling that might be helpful. Another option is using your posteriors as a feature vector--this is what is done in Tandem systems. That might not be exactly what you want, but will likely be much simpler.

Comment: Greetings and thanks for the reply. The vector of posterios I have basically IS the feature vector for the currently classified frame, so your ovservation is rather precise. HVite seems a good place for this, as it decodes. My worst fear is, that I also have to modify the FST...

Comment: Hi again, where would you start with treating the posteriors as a feature? Thanks, G.

Comment: It actually is not that difficult. The main issue is that since the HMM uses GMMs, it is best if the data looks like a Gaussian distribution. Posterior features typically are not, but taking the log of each feature is a good approximation. Another issue is if you use GMMs with diagonal covariance, this assumes the feature dimensions are independent. Again, this is not true for posterior features. Applying PCA is the typically work-around for this issue. To summarize, take the log of your features and then apply PCA.

Comment: Greetings again. Log likelihoods are already done, the PCA is a good idea. The main question again is -- where/ which files to change? Again HVite, same functions as before? IOW, what step/ function do I have to substitue. The htk code is the major problem :-) Thanks again for help, G.

Comment: Sorry I did not respond earlier; I was out of town for a week. If you are going to use your posteriors as features, then you do not need to touch the HTK code. All you need to do is write the features in a format HTK can read. If you have Matlab, you can use the function here (https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/matlab/matlab_htk/htkwrite.m) to do that. Note that the utility was not written by me. Once the posteriors are in the necessary format, you can train and decode your system using the standard HTK utilities.

Comment: Hi again, Only the test vectors are posteriors! They are computed from SVM-Results (training was performed on feature vectors and classifications from multiclass SVMS), and in the test stage, the decisions from those are transformed into posteriors via a sigmoid function. So no posterior features for the training phase, that is the most prominent issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option -f on HVite will present the result the way you wish.
Here is the command I send:

> ./HVite -T 1 -f -b sil -C config -a -H model/hmm7/macros -H model/hmm7/hmmdefs -i word1.mlf -m -t 250.0 -y lab -I word.mlf -S train.scp -L label/ dict.list phone1.list

and here is the beginning of the file word1.mlf (s2, s3, s4 are beginning center and end of each phoneme)

```
"mfc/dr1_fcjf0_sa1.lab"

0 100000 s2 -48.580540 sil -1204.165527 sil

100000 400000 s3 -158.456665

400000 1900000 s4 -997.128357

1900000 2000000 s2 -75.405327 SH -530.110291 SHE

2000000 2500000 s3 -306.394897

2500000 2700000 s4 -148.310074

2700000 3000000 s2 -252.779510 IY -796.414673

3000000 3300000 s3 -214.586655

3300000 3700000 s4 -329.048492
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the reply. Meanwhile, I have long since finished the project adding a lot of new code to HTK. Awful job, as the toolkit is written like it was 1982, but I got the job done. Thanks anyway, best regards!